# Unable to extract value from input field in python via beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am try to extract a value from a input field, using beautiful soup. I have tried all that I knew of, but it always returns None

I have tried using .text, .content and get_text() method properties, but still doesn't work.

```
results = requests.post(URL, data=payload_dict);
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, 'html.parser');
info = soup.find(class_='mandatory airport-complete');
print(info, end="-------\n")
print(info.attrs, end="-------\n")
print (info.value, end="-------\n")
print (info.contents, end="-------\n")
print (info.get_text(), end="-------\n")
```

Actual output:

```
<input class="mandatory airport-complete" data-complete-min-length="4" id="segments0departCity" name="searchAir.segments[0].departCity" onfocus="departCityFocus(this)" preferredcountry="NZ" title="Enter the departure city" type="text" value="Luang Prabang (LPQ)"> </input>"-------

{'type': 'text', 'id': 'segments0departCity', 'name': 'searchAir.segments[0].departCity', 'value': 'Luang Prabang (LPQ)', 'onfocus': 'departCityFocus(this)', 'title': 'Enter the departure city', 'data-complete-min-length': '4', 'preferredcountry': 'NZ', 'class': ['mandatory', 'airport-complete']}-------

None-------

[' ']-------
```

---

Expected:
`"Luang Prabang (LPQ)"`
Actually, I am interested in only the code LPQ, but can live with the whole value, by trying some patterns in regex

Screenshot of code and output dump from jupyter notebook..since this website seems to messup some formatting.
[p from juu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ9wi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'value': 'Luang Prabang (LPQ)',` is in your `info.attrs` dict it looks like? input is `info.attrs['value']` if I'm reading your outputs right.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your comment correctly but I have added a screenshot from the jupyter notebook to show exact values

Comment: Ok so, the second output, where you print `info.attrs`. That is a dictionary, which is a grouping of key:value pairs. If you look inside of that dictionary, there is a `'value'` key, with a value of `'Luang Prabang (LPQ)'`, which is the value you're looking for. In order to access that, try doing `print(info.attrs['value'])` This should print the `value` key's value, from the `info.attrs` dict

Comment: Glad to help :)